# Is SQL Server 2005 database compatible with 2008?

Tags: sql-server

I don't know if the title is correct but well what I'd like to ask: is it possible to import my database from SQL Server 2005 to 2008 or is the database in SQL Server 2005 compatible with 2008? I'm still a newbie.

Thanks

Comment: Yes you can. Backwards compatibility on the other hand is an issue for SQL Server

Comment: Yes it is. you can look at this [link](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/50055/restoring-bak-file-sql-server-2005-in-sql-server-2008) for more information.

Comment: oh i see, thanks and thanks for the link

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- You **can** restore an SQL Server 2005 database on SQL Server 2008.
- You **can not** restore an SQL Server 2008 database on SQL Server 2005.

Generally speaking, at the time of writing,

- you can restore any database starting from SQL Server 2005 on a **newer** version of SQL Server (up to 2016), and
- you can not restore any database on an earlier version.

You might want to increase the compatibility level of your DB after restoring it on a newer SQL Server version.

Comment: oh i see, thanks.. glad that i use server 2005 . Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Yes. They are compatible. You can use a backup to transfer all the data.